# Euler explicit in Fourier space

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to implement an explicit Euler scheme in the Fourier space in order to solve the unsteady heat equation in one dimension :

[image]

The scheme is written as :

[image]

With the Fourier series of the function f written as :

[image]

I wrote k , the wave number, as a value that "moves" along the values of this list :

```
liste = list(range(int(N/2)+1))+list(range(-int(N/2)+1,0))
```

And it works very well (I have already tested it in previous simulations).

In order to implement the Euler scheme I have created this function that should build the values of the coefficient step time by step time :

```
def update(Time,dt) : 
    
    liste = list(range(int(N/2)+1))+list(range(-int(N/2)+1,0))
    nt = int(Time/dt)
    T = np.zeros(N)
    
    for i in range(N):
        T[i]  = coef_fourier_initial[i]
    
    for k in range(nt):
        for i in range(N):
            
            H = T[i]*(-4*(np.pi**2)*liste[i]**2)
            tmp   = T + dt*H 
            T     = tmp 
    
    return T
```

Unfortunately when I try to run it for :

```
y_2 = update(0.1,0.001)
```

I have these none values that appear and I don't understand why ?

```
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan

nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan

nan nan nan nan]
```

In order to simplify the comprehension of my code here I put how I've implemented the values of the function at t = 0 :

```
N = 40 
x = np.linspace(0,1-(1/N),N) 
l = np.arange(N)
f = np.zeros(N)

for i in l:
    if i>=0 and i<=9 :
        f[i] = 0
    elif i>=10 and i<=19 :
        f[i] = 2*(x[i] - 0.25)
    elif i>=20 and i<=29 :
        f[i] = 2*(-x[i] + 0.75)
    elif i>=30 and i<=39:
        f[i] = 0
```

Then the base matrix MSPPH :

```
def MSPPH(N):

    matrice=np.zeros((N,N),dtype="complex")
    k=0
    liste=list(range(int(N/2)+1))+list(range(-int(N/2)+1,0))
    liste_imp=list(range(int((N-1)/2)+1))+list(range(-int((N-1)/2),0))

    if N%2==0:
        for t in liste:
            for i in range(N):
                x=i/N
                matrice[k,i]=np.exp(-2*t*np.pi*(1j)*x)
            k+=1

    else:
        for t in liste_imp:
            for i in range(N-1):
                x=i/N
                matrice[k,i]=np.exp(-2*t*np.pi*(1j)*x)
            k+=1

    return np.array(matrice,dtype="complex")
```

And how I have built the initial coefficient :

```
coef_fourier_initial = np.zeros(N) 
coef_fourier_initial = np.dot(MSPPH(N),f)
```

Could someone help me to understand my error ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's in `coef_fourier_initial`?  How do you initialize it?

Comment: In fact, it's a little bit complicated : `coef_fourier_initial` is the initial values of Fourier coefficients. The values of the initial condition of the function f is built as a 'triangle function' named simply 'f' in my code I've obtained the  `coef_fourier_initial` by multiplying this function with a typical base changement matrix MSPPH as : `coef_fourier_initial = np.dot(MSPPH(N),f)`. I've tested it and the values are perfectly correct.

Comment: Have you tried printing out T at the end of each outer loop?  One possibility is that T is growing too big and being replaced by +infinity. Then on the next loop through, you're adding +inf and -inf, which gives you nan.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer : I've tried to see the values of T after the first loop : it's true that it's growing too fast but I don't understand how to deal with it ? I've also edited my post in order to help you to understand how I've created `coef_fourier_initial`

Comment: Sorry.  At this point, the math is beyond me.  I was just surprised that within the inner loop, every element of T was being incremented, and there seemed to be no scaling going on.  I realized that an infinity could be the cause of your NaN.  Maybe some else can tell you why your code isn't matching the equations.

Comment: Thank you : I know that it's very complicated to bring a problem like this and try to understand how the solution works... Hope someone will try to help too :/ Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code, or some debugging to figure out in what line of code and what iteration the `nan`s are introduced in the array?

Comment: This is the exact error message that I've got : `<ipython-input-29-d1418edd1316>:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  H = T[i]*(-4*(np.pi**2)*liste[i]**2)
<ipython-input-29-d1418edd1316>:14: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  tmp   = T + dt*H`